# Can't see USB drives

Tags: usb

My Dash correctly lists my two USB hard drives, but when I open, for example, LibreOffice, and want to open a file in my usb drive, I don't see it.

Comment: If the drives aren't shown in the open dialog then you have to click "+ Other..."

Answer (score 1):

When you click **Open** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) in LibreOffice, you should see a window similar to this:

[image: Screenshot of Open dialog]

Click the up arrow shown here:

[image: Up arrow highlighted]

until you reach the root folder `/`, then double click to open the `media` folder:

[image: media folder]

There should be a folder labelled with your user name. If you open it, you'll see a list of external drives (SD cards, USBs, etc):

[image: list of drives]

Most likely, you were smart enough to give your device a label when you first got it (or it came with one) so it should be easy to identify.

Comment: Got it!  Thank You, I Would never have found it.

Comment: No problem! If it helped, you can mark it as accepted (to show that you don't need more help with this).